# onBlur event not allowing link clicks to register

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I have a Navigation Bar with a `React-InstantSearch: <SearchBox />` in that provides me with Autocomplete, there is an `onChange` event that fires that shows the suggestions box. There is also an `onBlur` event that fires when you leave the search box and hides the box. This `onBlur` event is preventing a link click from firing. (Verified by removing it). Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can correct this? Code below:

`Relevant Portion of App.js`

```
render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return (
        <div className="App-container">
          <InstantSearch
            appId="{MY APP ID}"
            apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_ALGOLIA_API_KEY}
            indexName="blog_posts"
          >
            <NavigationBar
              loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}
              handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
              username={this.state.username}
            />
            <Redirect to="/" />;
          </InstantSearch>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="App-container">
        <InstantSearch
          appId="{MY APP ID}"
          apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_ALGOLIA_API_KEY}
          indexName="blog_posts"
        >
          <NavigationBar
            loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}
            handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
            username={this.state.username}
          />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" />
            <Route path="/posts" component={PostListView} />
            <Route
              path="/post/:postID"
              render={props => (
                <PostDetailView
                  {...props}
                  loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}
                  username={this.state.username}
                  deleteComment={this.deleteComment}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/login"
              render={props => (
                <LoginForm {...props} handleLogin={this.handleLogin} />
              )}
            />
          </Switch>
        </InstantSearch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`NavigationBar.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Hits, SearchBox, Highlight } from "react-instantsearch-dom";

import CompanyHeader from "../config/settings.js";

/**
 * Navigation Bar for App
 * Utilizes react-bootstrap
 * @extends Component
 */
class NavigationBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hitResultsShown: false
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
  }

  onChange() {
    this.setState({
      hitResultsShown: true
    });
  }

  onBlur(e) {
    this.setState({
      hitResultsShown: false
    });
    e.target.value = "";
  }

  render() {
    const logged_in_nav = (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
          {`Hello, ${this.props.username}`}
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={3} onClick={this.props.handleLogout}>
          Logout
        </NavItem>
      </React.Fragment>
    );

    const logged_out_nav = (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/login">
          Log In
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={3} href="/signup">
          SignUp
        </NavItem>
      </React.Fragment>
    );

    return (
      // Instantiate a Navbar with:
      //   Dark Theme
      //   Full-width
      //   sticks to top of viewport
      <Navbar inverse fluid fixedTop>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="/">{CompanyHeader}</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/random">
              Random Post
            </NavItem>
            {this.props.loggedIn ? logged_in_nav : logged_out_nav}
          </Nav>

          <Navbar.Form pullRight>
            <SearchBox onChange={this.onChange} onBlur={this.onBlur} />
            {this.state.hitResultsShown ? <Hits hitComponent={PostHits} /> : ""}
          </Navbar.Form>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

class PostHits extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const hit = this.props.hit;
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="hit-name">
          <Link to={`/post/${hit.id}`}>
            <Highlight attribute="title" hit={hit} className="font--bold" />
          </Link>
        </span>
        <p className="well">
          {hit.content.length > 100 ? hit.content.slice(0, 100) : hit.content}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your onBlur is only wrapping the Searchbox component.

When you click on the suggestions box link you are removing focus from the Searchbox and subsequently hiding the suggestions.

All you have to do is wrap both of the elements within the onBlur and your problem will be solved:

```
<div onFocus={this.onChange} onBlur={this.onBlur} >
  <SearchBox />
  {this.state.hitResultsShown && <Hits hitComponent={PostHits} />}
</div>
```

Note: Inline conditional rendering is better like that ^ and onFocus will call it once instead of repeatedly like onChange will.

In a situation like this your suggestions box would normally be part of the Search component as it is inherently linked, pushing the blur/change functionality down into that component and making it a lot more self-contained.

Comment: unfortunately this did not solve my issue. Moving the on* methods to a container div had no effect.

Comment: Can you update your answer with what you tried? And have you attempted merging the autocomplete box into the search component? That's where it should be and will probably fix your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before. I solve with Hooks and a setTimeout for onBlur method with 200ms. That way, my child tab close right after i click on the link and my onChange worked fine too.

```
onBlur={()=>{setTimeout(() => {setSearch(false)}, "200")}}
```